# Dual boot Win 8.1 OK, Ubuntu 13.10 stops launch at GRUB4DOS

Tags: boot, grub2

I have scoured the net and this site and trying everything to get this to work. I have, currently, Windows 8.1 installed and I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 so I can dual boot them.

My hardware is the Asus G46VW with the most up-to-date bios, 210. UEFI is disabled along with Secure Boot and Fast Boot. I have the main OS, Windows 8, installed on my 64gig mSATA drive and I also have a 750gig internal HDD that I split in half. 400gigs for Windows storage and 350 for Ubuntu.

I have tried the LiveUSB boot and it doesn't ask to install Ubuntu along side my Windows installation. It says wipe entire disk or I have to choose "Something Else." I choose that and choose the partition I created for Ubuntu. Manually create the needed partitions and run the install. Once that is completed I reboot my system and it loads into Windows. I run EasyBCD, add the Ubuntu boot, save it and reboot. I get the screen asking what to load, Win 8.1 or Ubuntu. If I choose Windows it loads up just fine to the desktop. If I choose Ubuntu it brings me to a prompt called GRUB4DOS.

This is where I am stuck. I have tried nearly everything to get this working and to no avail. I have tried a lot of solutions to get past the GRUB4DOS screen but I cannot. I have no problems blowing everything away and starting again as I really need to get this to work.

Comment: I just had a problem with my dual boot after upgrading win8 to win8.1 and in the end all I had to do was reinstall grub to the boot partition. Then both show up in the grub menu on  boot.

Comment: @dibs: Do you have a link to show how that is done? I have found some information on how to reinstall grub but it is quite elaborite and was curious if you knew of an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this, but I think that it is happening because Windows 8.1 is new and the programmers of Ubuntu haven't already found the way to add them to OS.